# How to publish to AWS MQTT after message was received

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mqtt

After importing the AWSIoTMQTTClient module with

```
from AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib import AWSIoTMQTTClient
```

I went ahead and configured the MQTT client connection

```
myMQTTClient = AWSIoTMQTTClient("my-clientid")
myMQTTClient.configureEndpoint("123abc-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", 8883)
myMQTTClient.configureCredentials(ROOT_KEY, PRIVATE_KEY, CERT) 
myMQTTClient.connect()
```

I defined `helloworld` function that I want to use as a callback to catch the messages from the topic as:

```
def helloworld(client, params, packet):
    print('...topic:', packet.topic)
    print('...payload:', packet.payload)
    myMQTTClient.publish(topic="home/fromserver", QoS=1, payload="{'message':'hello from server'}" )
```

Please note that the last line in the `helloworld` function I publish the message back to MQTT to the "home/from-server" topic.

I added two more lines to the script and run it

```
myMQTTClient.subscribe("home/to-server", 1, helloworld)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

I can fetch the messages from the `to-server` topic. But publishing the message to `from-server` topic crashes with `AWSIoTExceptions.publishTimeoutException`

How can I publish a message back to MQTT without raising the `publishTimeoutException`?